# nested routes with double id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-routing

I am starting with rails and I am having a issue on nested routes with 2 ids.

I submit a form from:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/worlds/1/banks/new
```

And I get redirect to:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin/worlds/23/banks/23
```

(with 23 being the id of the new bank)

The problem is that I can't force this url to keep the first `id = 1` as on the first route after the create action.

My `Admin::Bank` controller on the create here:

```
def create
  @world_bank = Admin::Bank.new(params[:admin_banque])
  @world_bank.world_id = params[:id]
  @world_bank.save!
  redirect_to admin_bank_path(@world_bank.world_id, @world_bank.id)
end
```

Routes:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :mondes do
      member do
        resources :banques
    end
  end
end
```

And rake routes:

```
admin_banks GET    /admin/worlds/:id/banks(.:format)          admin/banks#index
POST   /admin/worlds/:id/banks(.:format)          admin/banks#create
new_admin_bank GET    /admin/worlds/:id/banks/new(.:format)      admin/banks#new
edit_admin_bank GET    /admin/worlds/:id/banks/:id/edit(.:format) admin/banks#edit
admin_bank GET    /admin/worlds/:id/banks/:id(.:format)      admin/banks#show
PUT    /admin/worlds/:id/banks/:id(.:format)      admin/banks#update
DELETE /admin/worlds/:id/banks/:id(.:format)      admin/banks#destroy
```

The fact is that I see:

`:id/thing/:id/stuff` when I know I should get `:world_it/thing/:id/stuff`

I've tried different way to use the redirect, especially the `redirect_to admin_banks(world_id, id)` for example, but it stayed the same.

I am pretty sure this could be fixed with a match in the routes.rb but I can't make it work for now...

Comment: It seems you put the wrong routes code here. I dont see `worlds` and `banks` resources there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the :member block around your nested resource & it should work. Try:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :mondes do
    resources :banques
  end
end
```